How to pause the game and the coroutine when a cycle of scaling and rotation ending?
this is what i tried. in the bottom i'm using
Time.timeScale = 0f;    
yield break;

but it's never pausing the game.
i also tried instead the line
yield return null;

to make
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

but it's not pausing the game either.
i tried first only
 Time.timeScale = 0f; 

then tried with also break; and then also added
StopAllCoroutines();

but nothing is working so far.
here is the full script:
using System.Collections;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool coroutineIsRunning = false;

    private Quaternion endRotationScaleDown;
    bool rotationAndScalingComplete = false;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (automatic)
        {
            if (!coroutineIsRunning)
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Scale()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);
        }

        scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, scaleUp ? maxSize : minSize, duration, scaleUp));
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, bool isScalingUp)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;
        Quaternion startRotation = targetObj.transform.rotation;

        Quaternion endRotationScaleUp = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0); // Example end rotation when scaling up
        Quaternion endRotationScaleDown = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0); // Example end rotation when scaling down

        // Generate a random angle (0 or 1)
        int randomAngle = Random.Range(0, 2);

        // Set the rotation angle based on the random value
        float t = (randomAngle == 0) ? 180f : -180f;

        // Choose the end rotation based on the scaling direction.
        Quaternion endRotation = isScalingUp ? endRotationScaleUp : Quaternion.Euler(0, t, 0);

        targetObj.transform.rotation = endRotation;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            float lerpFactor = counter / duration;

            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, lerpFactor);
            targetObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, lerpFactor);

            if (counter >= duration)
            {
                coroutineIsRunning = false;
                // Ensuring the final state matches exactly
                targetObj.transform.localScale = toScale;
                targetObj.transform.rotation = endRotation;

                rotationAndScalingComplete = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        if (rotationAndScalingComplete)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            yield break;
        }
    }
}


What exactly are you trying to do? Does your scaling work now?

In general I'm personally against such while loops. It takes a while to figure out and maintain what exactly is being looped here.
Instead I'd recommend to use a clean deterministic for loop like for instance
for(var counter = 0f; counter < duration; counter += Time.deltaTime)
{
    var lerpFactor = counter / duration;
    targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, lerpFactor);
    targetObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, lerpFactor);

    yield return null;
}
// ensure clean final values
targetObject.transform.localScale = toScale;
targetObj.transform.rotation = endRotation;

// enabled next routine 
coroutineIsRunning = false;

Time.timeScale = 0f;

This should help to reduce complexity and understand what is happening step by step with less flags and if checks.
Of course you could achieve the same also with the while and simply move the inner block after the loop as I did above. imho the for just reads better and is saver regarding forgetting to increase the counter.
In theory you could even directly iterate over the lerpFactor using
for(var lerpFactor = 0f; lerpFactor < 1; lerpFactor += Time.deltaTime / duration)

but I prefer to iterate over the duration for better readability
Next simply place a debug log or breakpoint at the line that supposedly pauses the game.
If it is indeed reached but things are not being stopped - I suppose

either some other script is affecting the time scale as well
or your other things that happen in the app are not affected by scaled time at all (like e.g. when using Time.unscaledTime/Time.unscaledDeltaTime etc

